# Using Model method waterline

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline, koa

I'm starting with koa and waterline ORM. I have a problem when I try to use "testFucntion" method from this waterline model from my controller:

```
"use strict";
//https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs
var Waterline = require('waterline');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

var User = Waterline.Collection.extend({
    identity: 'user',
    connection: 'default',
    attributes: {
        username: {
            type: 'string',
            required: true,
        },
        password: {
            type: 'string',
            minLength: 6,
            maxLength: 21
        }
    },

    //test function
    testFucntion: function *(params) {
        ...
        console.log('inside');
    }
});
```

The code I'm using to execute the method is :

```
function *(){
    var params= this.request.body
    var userModel = this.models.user;
    var result = yield userModel.testFucntion(params)
}
```

I dont know if this kind of functions are public and how can I use it from outside...

Answer (score 0):

The custom methods on the model need to go under the `attributes` node. Where you have it is for the model specification and event lifecycle methods (we all make that mistake at first).